# Can you operate / permanently install an air compressor in freezing temperatures?

Tags: garage, electric-motor, compressor

My garage is heated but it's attic is not. The attic is accessible and could make a good location for a large air compressor - saves space & could muffle the noise. But the annual temperature swings in the attic are a concern.

- Winter temps here can go down, at the extreme, to < -10 F (-23 C).
- Summer highs might be less of a concern, but get into the 80s/90s (26/32) outside - probably > 100 F (37 C) in the attic.

Aside from whether extreme temps could be harmful to the motor or compressor pump itself, the tank is bound to get some condensation in it. I would plan to have a drain tube / valve plumbed in, but I wonder if frozen ice inside the compressor tank could cause an issue?

I checked a [manufacturer's manual](https://manuals.harborfreight.com/manuals/93000-93999/93274.pdf) for a somewhat expensive compressor and it literally says nothing about operating temperature.

Reading around internet forums I get kind of a mixed impression - nothing that seems conclusive.

There are indeed some compressors used outside all the time - like at gas stations for filling tires. But those might have been purpose built for the conditions so I don't infer much about a standard workshop compressor from that.

Comment: The summer heat will be bad for the life of the compressor/motor, and also for the amount of water in the air (the amount that will not come out as condensate, as the tank will be so hot between being in a hot attic and attached to a poorly cooled compressor in a hot attic.) That's also one heck of a load on a part of the garage that is rarely built for anything more than light storage, if even that.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the attic has a portion that was finished; even though the rest is not I think it was built for occupancy loads throughout. Regardless the weight will certainly be spread across several trusses, I think the lbs/sqft will be acceptable even though I know its closer to a point load on them individually.

Answer (score 3):

Ice in the tank is not going to cause a problem.  The issue is using the air in sub-freezing temps.  Ice can form in the hose or in the tool.  A good solution is to install a water separator that will catch the water before it goes into the hose and freezes.

Answer (score 1):

This Practical Machinist [forum post](https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/general/educate-me-quincy-325-air-compressor-pumps-found-one-200-a-275357-post3089585/#post3089585) by Lakeside53 says the following:

> Look in the Quincy manual (you can get it online). The oil you use
> depends of the temperature. If your compressor is "inside" and/or not
> subject to freezing, Quincy recommends 30 SAE (ISO 100) non-detergent
> hydraulic oil. Outside low temperatures -down as low as 10 SAE.

I need to see if I can find the original source for this. But it implies that many compressor heads at least will operate just fine in the cold assuming they are properly setup.